# Lead to Opportunity trigger

Tags: trigger

I need a trigger that looks for a lead with the lead source Price Freeze and automatically converts it to an opportunity.

Comment: you might want to check out [ask]

Comment: I need a large Dunkin Donuts Coffee with cream and sugar

Comment: can i get a unicorn?

Comment: Ok, can someone tell me where to go to learn how to write a trigger? I thought this would be a good place to start, but I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Use this ...Happy Coding :-

```
for(Lead myLead: Trigger.new) {
    if((myLead.isconverted==false) && (myLead.ProfileStatus__c == 'Paid profile')) {// Put your condition here** 
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(myLead.Id);
        lc.convertedStatus = 'Qualified';
        lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(false); //Put this flag to false to create opportunity

        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        }
  }
```